# 500 Internal Server Error Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I made a Unity project but, every time I need launch my function Post I get this exception

500 Internal Server Error
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Conexion.cs:69)

thanks.

```
private IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www) {
    yield return www;
    // check for errors
    if (www.error == null) {
        results = www.text;
        Debug.Log(results);
        webserviceResponse(results);
        //onComplete();
    } else {
        Debug.Log (www.error);  //error at this line
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't tell us which webserver you are querying with exactly what data, we can't help you. A `500` error means you sent something which crashes the server-side logic or wasn't expected otherwise. Is this is querying against a self-written web server (php script or something) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

**500 Internal Server Error** is an HTTP Response code.

The Web Server you are making your request to is responding with an HTTP Status Code 500, which is either due to your application posting an invalid request or the server containing a bug of it's own.

Either way this has nothing to do with Unity.

Here is the link to the W3 Specifications for this error : 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

*Internal Error 500
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.*